# Overwrite single function of gtest default_result_printer

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to change the way gtest prints the "error messages" when a test fails.
The documentations suggests to create a class that inherits from `testing::EmptyTestEventListener` and implementing the `OnTestPartResult(...)` function to do so.
The problem is: That way I have to reimplement the whole default result printer, because all the other functions like `OnTestEnd(...)` whould be empty at first. I only want to change the way gtest prints the results but I like the way everything else is displayed.
If I add my new Event Listener to the EventListeners List without deleting the standard one from it, it prints both messages (mine and the standard) as one would expect.

Is there a way to overwrite the single `OnTestPartResult(...)` function of the `standard_result_printer` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do smth like this sketch, not tested:

```
class MyTestListener : public testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
 public:
  EmptyTestEventListener() {
    default_result_printer_ = UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners()->default_result_printer();
    UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners()->Release(default_result_printer_);
    UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners()->SetDefaultResultPrinter(this);
  }

  ~EmptyTestEventListener() {
    UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners()->Release(this);
    UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners()->SetDefaultResultPrinter(default_result_printer_);
  }

  void OnTestEnd(const TestInfo& test_info) override {
    default_result_printer_->OnTestEnd(test_info);
  }

  // ...

 private:
  TestEventListener* default_result_printer_;
};
```